# Second Order Chain Rule in Higher Dimensions

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

If we have functions $f$ and $g,$ we know that
$$ D(g \circ f)_x = (Dg)_{f(x)} \circ (Df)_{x}$$

We then have
\begin{align*} 
(D^{2}(g \circ f))_{x} &= D((Dg)_{f(x)} \circ (Df)_{x}) \\
&= (D^{2}g)_{f(x)} \circ (Df)^{2}_{x} + (Dg)_{f(x)} \circ (D^{2}f)_{x}
\end{align*}

as stated in my textbook (Pugh's *Real Mathematical Analysis*).

I understand that we have to use the Leibniz Rule to expand from the first equality to the second, but where is the $(Df)^{2}_{x}$ term coming from?

Comment: You use the same notation for multiply and composition

Comment: @dmtri There is only that operation in the formula, composition.

Comment: @ksankar The first thing is to understand to what function is the second $D$ being applied to. It is not to the function $(Dg)_{f(x)}\circ (Df)_x$, for a fixed $x$, that inputs a vector and returns another vector. That function is linear and its differential is itself. They are applying to the function $x\mapsto (h\mapsto ((Dg)_{f(x)}\circ (Df)_x)(h))$, that inputs $x$ and returns the linear map $(Dg)_{f(x)}\circ (Df)_x$. The compositional factor $(Dg)_{y}(w)$ is composed with $y=f(x)$ and with $w=(Df)_x$. What is being applied is the chain rule for a function of two variables $y$ and $w$.

Comment: @OscarRascal, In the second line of the OP's question we see: $D(g \circ f)_x = (Dg)_{f(x)} \circ (Df)_{x}$

Comment: @dmtri Yes, that is the chain rule. I don't know what else you mean when you say that we see it.

Comment: @OscarRascal, I mean that it should be written as: $D(g \circ f)_x = (Dg)_{f(x)} (Df)_{x}$, that is multiplication of real numbers.

Comment: @dmtri No, it should be written the way that it is written. $(Dg)_{f(x)}$ and $(Df)_x$ are not real numbers. They are linear functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ and from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^k$ for some $m,n,k$, that are being composed.

Comment: @OscarRascal Thanks for the explanation! I'm still unsure of how you can apply the chain rule to $(Dg)_{y}(w)$ as you've defined it.

Answer (score 1):

Both terms appear already in the $ 1 $-dimensional case, so let's look at that.  So we have $ z = g ( y ) $ and $ y = f ( x ) $, so that $ z = ( g \circ f ) ( x ) $.  Then by the Chain Rule, $ \mathrm d z / \mathrm d x = g ' \big ( f ( x ) \big ) f ' ( x ) $.  So by the Product Rule and then the Chain Rule again, $$ \frac { \mathrm d ^ 2 z } { \mathrm d x ^ 2 } = \frac { \mathrm d \Big ( g ' \big ( f ( x ) \big ) \Big ) } { \mathrm d x } f ' ( x ) + g ' \big ( f ( x ) \big ) \frac { \mathrm d \big ( f ' ( x ) \big ) } { \mathrm d x } = g ' ' \big ( f ( x ) \big ) f ' ( x ) f ' ( x ) + g ' \big ( f ( x ) \big ) f ' ' ( x ) \text . $$  So you can see that we get $ f ' ( x ) ^ 2 $ in the first term, where one factor of $ f ' ( x ) $ is left over from the $ f ' ( x ) $ that appears in the order-$ 1 $ Chain Rule, while the the other factor of $ f ' ( x ) $ appears from applying the Chain Rule to $ g ' \circ f $.  Now it's basically just a shift of notation to turn $ ( g \circ f ) ' ' ( x ) = g ' ' \big ( f ( x ) \big ) f ' ( x ) ^ 2 + g ' \big ( f ( x ) \big ) f ' ' ( x ) $ into $ \big ( \mathrm D ^ 2 ( g \circ f ) \big ) _ x = ( \mathrm D ^ 2 g ) _ { f ( x ) } \circ ( \mathrm D f ) _ x ^ 2 + ( \mathrm D g ) _ { f ( x ) } \circ ( \mathrm D ^ 2 f ) _ x $.  Of course, somebody still has to prove that this rule continues to hold in any number of dimensions, but maybe that gives you an idea of where each term comes from.

That ends the answer, but I also want to be clear about what sort of thing a second derivative is in this context.  If $ f $ is a twice-differentiable function from (a subset $ U $ of) $ \mathbb R ^ m $ to $ \mathbb R ^ n $, so that $ ( \mathrm D f ) _ x $ is a linear transformation from $ \mathbb R ^ m $ to $ \mathbb R ^ n $ for each $ x $ in the domain $ U $ of $ f $, then $ \mathrm D f $ itself is a function from $ U $ to $ \operatorname { Lin } ( \mathbb R ^ m , \mathbb R ^ n ) \cong \mathbb R ^ { m n } $.  Thus, $ ( \mathrm D ^ 2 f ) _ x $ is (for $ x $ in $ U $) a linear transformation from $ \mathbb R ^ m $ to $ \operatorname { Lin } ( \mathbb R ^ m , \mathbb R ^ n ) $.  Similarly, if $ g $ is a twice-differentiable function from (a subset $ V $ of) $ \mathbb R ^ n $ to $ \mathbb R ^ p $, then (assuming that $ V $ contains the range of $ f $) each $ ( \mathrm D g ) _ { f ( x ) } $ is (for $ x \in U $) a linear transformation from $ \mathbb R ^ n $ to $ \mathbb R ^ p $, while each $ ( \mathrm D ^ 2 g ) _ { f ( x ) } $ is a linear transformation from $ \mathbb R ^ n $ to $ \operatorname { Lin } ( \mathbb R ^ n , \mathbb R ^ p ) $.  So while it's perfectly straightforward to compose $ ( \mathrm D g ) _ { f ( x ) } $ and $ ( \mathrm D f ) _ x $ to get the linear transformation $ \big ( \mathrm D ( g \circ f ) \big ) _ x $ from $ \mathbb R ^ m $ to $ \mathbb R ^ p $, it's not as obvious how to compose things to make $ \big ( \mathrm D ^ 2 ( g \circ f ) \big ) _ x $ a linear transformation from $ \mathbb R ^ m $ to $ \operatorname { Lin } ( \mathbb R ^ m , \mathbb R ^ p ) $.

So to be clear, in the second term in the expression from Pugh's book, first $ ( \mathrm D ^ 2 f ) _ x $ takes a vector in $ \mathbb R ^ m $ and transforms it linearly into a linear transformation from $ \mathbb R ^ m $ to $ \mathbb R ^ n $, and then we compose $ ( \mathrm D g ) _ { f ( x ) } $ with this linear transformation, thus transforming it linearly into a linear transformation from $ \mathbb R ^ m $ to $ \mathbb R ^ p $.  And in the first term (the one that you were asking about), first $ ( \mathrm D f ) _ x $ takes a vector in $ \mathbb R ^ m $ and transforms it linearly into a vector in $ \mathbb R ^ n $, then $ ( \mathrm D ^ 2 g ) _ { f ( x ) } $ transforms this vector linearly into a linear transformation from $ \mathbb R ^ n $ to $ \mathbb R ^ p $, and then we compose this linear transformation with $ ( \mathrm D f ) _ x $ to get a linear transformation from $ \mathbb R ^ m $ to $ \mathbb R ^ p $.  And of course, after all of that, we add the two linear transformations from $ \mathbb R ^ m $ to $ \mathbb R ^ p $, and this is what $ \big ( D ^ 2 ( g \circ f ) \big ) _ x $ transforms a vector in $ \mathbb R ^ m $ linearly into.

ETA:  Another way to think of the second derivative is to use the natural isomorphism between $ \operatorname { Lin } \big ( \mathbb R ^ m , \operatorname { Lin } ( \mathbb R ^ m , \mathbb R ^ n ) \big ) $ and $ \operatorname { Lin } ( \mathbb R ^ m \otimes \mathbb R ^ m , \mathbb R ^ n ) \cong \operatorname { Bilin } ( \mathbb R ^ m , \mathbb R ^ n ) $.  That is, $ ( \mathrm D ^ 2 f ) _ x $ can be thought of as a bilinear transformation (taking two arguments) from $ \mathbb R ^ m $ to $ \mathbb R ^ n $.  Then this composes with $ ( \mathrm D g ) _ { f ( x ) } $, a linear transformation from $ \mathbb R ^ n $ to $ \mathbb R ^ p $, to produce a bilinear transformation from $ \mathbb R ^ m $ to $ \mathbb R ^ p $.  The interpretation of $ ( \mathrm D f ) _ x ^ 2 $ in the term that you were asking about is then really the tensor square $ ( \mathrm D f ) _ x \otimes ( \mathrm D f ) _ x $, a linear transformation from $ \mathbb R ^ m \otimes \mathbb R ^ m $ to $ \mathbb R ^ n \otimes \mathbb R ^ n $, or equivalently a bilinear transformation from $ \mathbb R ^ m $ to $ \mathbb R ^ n \otimes \mathbb R ^ n $.  This then composes with $ ( \mathrm D ^ 2 g ) _ { f ( x ) } $, a bilinear transformation from $ \mathbb R ^ n $ to $ \mathbb R ^ p $, to produce another bilinear transformation from $ \mathbb R ^ m $ to $ \mathbb R ^ p $.  You can think of that first term as taking two vectors from $ \mathbb R ^ m $, transforming them each separately with $ ( \mathrm D f ) _ x $ to vectors in $ \mathbb R ^ n $, and then letting $ ( \mathrm D ^ 2 g ) _ { f ( x ) } $ transform the pair of them bilinearly to a vector in $ \mathbb R ^ p $.  This is probably more in line with how Pugh was thinking of the composition, given the notation used.